# How can I get PropertyInfor of Items in a unknow List type (List<UnknowType>)

Tags: c#

I have a method that will get all Property of a type T "GetPropertiesInfor() where T : new()" but if there is a List in T I cannot get PropertyInfor of UnknowType in the list.

For this, I'm currently searching for a solution on internet but I don't know if my keyword for searching is correct or not.

This is my method:

```
//Get ProperTyInfor of a type T
    public void GetPropertiesInfor<T>() where T : new()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        List<PropertyInfo> mpropertyInfos = 
        obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
        for (int i=0;i< mpropertyInfos.Count;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("property type ["+ i + "] = " 
             + mpropertyInfos[i].PropertyType);
            //If property i of T is type of List

  if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(mpropertyInfos[i].PropertyType)) 
            {
             //now I know this property mpropertyInfos[i] is type of list
             //how can I get PropertyInfor of Items in the list
            }
        }
    }
```

If mpropertyInfos[i] is a type of List, I want to get All PropertyInfor of items that the List will stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all you need to do call is `type.GetGenericArguments()[0]` assuming you have just one parameter (as a List will have)

```
if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(mpropertyInfos[i].PropertyType)))
    var genericParam = mpropertyInfos[i].PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

---

[Type.GetGenericArguments Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns an array of Type objects that represent the type arguments of
>   a closed generic type or the type parameters of a generic type
>   definition.

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral, you just save my life

Comment: @user2905416 its not advisable to pin your life on software :P